# How can I create a recursively typed graph(a graph of graph)?

Tags: java, c#-4.0, haskell, language-agnostic, static-typing

I want to create a graph structure which can be used to represent higher level graphs too. I think the problem is best expressed through a figure:
[image: Recursive Graph]

As you may have noticed, a graph of level `n-1` contains nodes of level `n`. There are no mixed graphs i.e. all nodes in the graph have the same level.

Another aspect of my use case is that the node is basically just a function. So a level 1 graph is an interconnection of functions(think neural networks).

I also need the connection matrix of the graph to be an independent object rather than a property of the node(i.e. I need some object to represent all connections, rather than `Node.Next` as a property on every node).

A psedocode approach I have in mind is:

```
class Node<T>:
    func :: T -> T //The function 'func' takes a value of type 'T' and returns another value of type 'T'.

class Network<T where T is instance of Node> inherits Node<T2>:
    ConnectionMatrix<T> matrix;
    override/implement func :: T2 -> T2;

//I'm applying some sort of pattern matching on types here:
type ConnectionMatrix<Network<T>> = 
    Dictionary<Nerwork<T>, Dictionary<Nerwork<T>, ConnectionMatrix<T>>>
type ConnectionMatrix<Node> = Dictionary<Node, Dictionary<Node, Integer>>
```

But as you can see it is incomplete, and as it stands can't be represented in any language I know.

The language of implementation should not be an issue as long as it isn't dynamically typed.

**Edit:**
The following solution(as suggested in an answer) will not work by my design:

```
data Connection = Connection {
    weight :: Double,
    length :: Int
} deriving (Eq, Show)

data Graph a = Graph {
    nodes :: M.Map Int a,
    edges :: M.Map (Int, Int) Connection
} deriving (Eq, Show)

data Network a = Simple a | Nested (Network (Graph a))
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

The reason is that I need a weighted graph such that:

- Connection between two Level 0 graphs(i.e. simple nodes) is the same as the above defined `Connection` type.
- Connections between two Level 1 graphs will be of type `M.Map (Int, Int) Connection`, hence the edges of the graph should will be of type `M.Map (Int, Int) (M.Map (Int, Int) Connection)`. This means that each edge in a level 1 graph returns a set of connections between the inner nodes of the level 0 graph.
- Similarly, for a Level n graph, the type of the connection should be `M.Map (Int, Int) <Type of connection for Level n-1 graph>`.

**Edit:** Actually the above representation can work for me; I just need to store the edges in a reduced form. But is it possible to write a program to satisfy the above conditions?

Answer (score 2):

You can represent a nodes of a graph as thing that has an unique label and a values. This way the value can be arbitrary (a function) without any constraints, and the labels are used to identify the nodes. Then you can represent the graph as two maps: One maps node labels to their values and the other maps node labels to the neighbouring nodes.

```hs
import qualified Data.Set as S
import qualified Data.Map as M

data Graph l a = Graph
    { nodes :: M.Map l a
    , edges :: M.Map l (S.Set l)
    }
```

If you want networks with type-static depths, you can define just

```hs
type Graph0 l a = a
type Graph1 l a = Graph l a
type Graph2 l a = Graph l (Graph l a)
-- etc
```

If you want to have networks of variable depth (which I assume is the thing you want) you can define a recursive data type where the recursion is non-uniform, like

```hs
data Network l a = Level0 a | LevelUp (Network l (Graph l a))
```

Then each value of type `Network` contains a graph of of the same level as the number of `Network` constructors it contains, and this is enforced by the type system. For example a 2-level graph can be constructed using

```hs
LevelUp . LevelUp . Level0 :: Graph l (Graph l a) -> Network l a
```

Comment: Hey, I just edited my question to give the reason why this solution won't work. However, I must say I'm surprised at the succinctness of the Network type. It took me 3 hours to figure out what exactly was happening(my lack of knowledge of haskell's Map and Set data types did not help).